# Clarity Design - Form layouts and controls

Tags: vmware-clarity

I was evaluating Clarity Design to migrate a large enterprise application to Angular/[material??/bootstrap??/Clarity??]..Currently it has an engine to Dynamically generate forms/display grids etc etc..all from backend supplied meta-data.

Though Clarity seem to be winning so far and have given good results in the dynamic grid/forms area , I am a bit stuck at the 'forms' layout, controls , labels etc etc..which is an essential part of a large enterprise application.

Issues are in the  margins, paddings etc etc. which is a problem when you have large forms which dont 'fit' the viewport.

One way to go about will be painstakingly thorwing in a bunch of 'css' but that might take away the design from the original. That might also affect some other components in the system.

**QUESTION:**Is there anyone out there managed to customise the Clarity css but not deviated much from the original ?? Can someone give me some pointers or samples ? Many have talked about custom theme which I am not very keen on.

Comment: Clarity offers custom themes for consumers to be able to customize components (generally colors of things). Search for `Custom Themes` in the docs about 3/4 down the page: https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/v0.13/themes

Comment: The forms are in the process of being updated. Some components are already available but the documentation has not been updated yet. A good place to start is the release notes here: https://vmware.github.io/clarity/news/0.12.0-beta.4  and new forms components have been released in the `ClrFormsNextModule`. Another good place to look for example code is in the demos used for development here: https://github.com/vmware/clarity/tree/master/src/dev/src/app/forms